# How to jump to correct method definition when more than one tags match?

Tags: vim, ctags

I've tried to generate the tag file by:

```
ctags -R * −−java−kinds=+mc
```

But when there are more than one matches, ctrl+] always jump to the wrong method definition in another class.

I know I can use :tjump to select if there's more than one option. But I hope there's better solution(if any)?

Comment: Have a look at `:help tag-priority`

Answer (score 14):

In such cases, I'd recommend using `g CTRL-]` instead of `CTRL-]`. Like `:tjump`, this will list all available tag matches and query you instead of jumping to the first.

To make this the default, you can use this mapping:

```
:nnoremap <C-]> g<C-]>
```

Comment: Hi, do you have any clue on [this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1269284/vim-does-not-jump-to-correct-line-of-tag-chosen-in-tselect-match-list)?

Comment: so i guess, there is no way for `ctags` to know. We must, therefore, list them and we do the choosing.

Answer (score -1):

Neither ctags nor vim have the ability to guess what the correct tag is and there's no way around that beside `:tjump` or `:tselect`. `:tag` has a priority mechanism that you can read about in the doc but that's still pretty dumb.

Cscope is a little smarter but not that much.

Given that situation, listing possible targets for you to choose is the only sane and practical approach.