# Vim does not jump to correct line of tag chosen in :tselect match list

Tags: vim, ctags

When I type `:tselect pool`, there are matches listed as expected:

```
  # pri kind tag               file
  1 F C m    poll              pika/adapters/select_connection.py
               line:238 class:IOLoop
               def poll(self):
  2 F C m    poll              pika/adapters/select_connection.py
               line:544 class:_PollerBase
               def poll(self):
  3 F C m    poll              pika/adapters/select_connection.py
               line:682 class:SelectPoller
               def poll(self):
```

but whatever number I choose, vim always jump to the line of the first choice, in this case, line 238. I tried `:tn`/`:tp`, tag number will change, but still on the same line.

corresponding lines in `tags` file:

```
poll    pika/adapters/select_connection.py      /^    def poll(self):$/;"       m       line:238        class:IOLoop
poll    pika/adapters/select_connection.py      /^    def poll(self):$/;"       m       line:544        class:_PollerBase
poll    pika/adapters/select_connection.py      /^    def poll(self):$/;"       m       line:682        class:SelectPoller
```

my `~/.ctag`:

```
--recurse
--links=no
--fields=+n
```

ctags version is `Exuberant Ctags 5.8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to another [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796034/vim-tnext-doesnt-move-cursor-to-the-next-tag), to work with vim, I should use `ctags -n` or `--excmd=number`, after adding this option to `~/.ctags`, it works fine now.

`--excmd=number` force ctags only use line number in tag file for locating, even though there is a `line:` column, but apparently, vim can't recognize it.

this is how `tags` looks now:

```
poll    pika/adapters/select_connection.py      238;"   m       line:238        class:IOLoop
poll    pika/adapters/select_connection.py      544;"   m       line:544        class:_PollerBase
poll    pika/adapters/select_connection.py      682;"   m       line:682        class:SelectPoller
```

the main difference is the third column, which vim called `{tagaddress}`:

> {tagaddress}  The Ex command that positions the cursor on the tag.  It can
>         be any Ex command, although restrictions apply (see
>         |tag-security|).  Posix only allows line numbers and search
>         commands, which are mostly used.

I believe that is the reason why pattern doesn't work.